# how to stop rubocop errors about ffi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rubocop

Working in Rubymine form windows using wsl and running everything with wsl terminal Im getting the following error from rubocop all the time:

```
Error:/home/dor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in `block in materialize': Could not find ffi-1.15.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /home/dor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /home/dor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /home/dor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
    from /home/dor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
    from /home/dor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
    from /home/dor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
    from /home/dor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
    from /home/dor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
    from /home/dor/ ...
```

this is quite annoying.
also bundle keeps asking to bundle install together with this error which I ran and did not help

Comment: is `rubocop` trying to run for a different ruby version? The error trace shows ruby version `2.6.5`, but perhaps your ruby project (and therefore anything installed via `bundle install`) is for a different ruby version (e.g. `2.7.x`). You might need to configure rubymine to run `bundle exec rubocop` to be explicit.

Comment: i only have 1 ruby version installed so this is unlikely

Comment: When you "ran bundle install", you say this "did not help". But what did it actually do? Did it install anything? Did it show an error message? Is there an `ffi` gem installed? Try running `bundle list` to see.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever command you are running, make sure that you're using `bundle exec`, for example:

```
$ bundle exec rubocop
```

Next, you can try the following:

- Install `ffi` manually to see if your Gem path is set up correctly: `gem install ffi`
- Re-install bundler: `gem uninstall bundler && gem install bundler`
- Remove the `Gemfile.lock` file (make a backup) and re-run `bundle install`.
- Run `bundle update` or `bundle update ffi`
- Try `bundle --full-index` ([ref](https://bundler.io/v1.2/bundle_install.html))

I see that you're not using JRuby, but I've also had problems where I had to use `bundler` (with an *R*) instead of `bundle` for JRuby, so you could try that.

For WSL specifically, I also found other people having this issue with Jekyll and WSL. The solution was to fix the GEM path. Follow the instructions [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/troubleshooting/#no-sudo).

If still none of this helps you, please describe how you're installing Ruby on WSL and what command you are using that produces this error.

Comment: so this is not for certain, but it seems removing the gemfile lock running bundle install and than returning it (so the project will run) fixed the issue